# How to set up Objective-J and Cappuccino

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I am trying to start development in Objective-J but I am completely lost as to how to set it up. The documentation about setting it up, didn't really help me. I am very familiar with web development and Objective-C so I can write the programs if I can get everything set up. Could somebody please give me step-by-step directions as to how to set it up on my (shared) server?

[This little "tutorial"](http://cappuccino.org/learn/tutorials/getting-setup.php) didn't help me out at all.

Comment: Please tell us what you've already done and what problem exactly you are facing.

Comment: I don't know where to start. And once I am to get it set up, I don't know how to "compile" the Objective-J code to JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the [Cappuccino download](http://cappuccino.org/download/) page and download the starter package. Unzip it into a folder your choice. Congratulations, you now have your first Cappuccino app ready to run! If you are using Safari you can open up `index-debug.html` right away and start trying out the starter app. (If you use other browsers like Chrome and Firefox they might not allow you to run a web app from a file:// URL. Instead you'll need to start up a web server and surf to the `index-debug.html` file through the server.)

Then you can start to edit the sample application right away and explore.

Once you are ready to learn more, take a look at these [Cappuccino tutorials](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/tutorials/) and instructions. They are still under development - we're not quite there with our new site yet - but they are definitely more up to date.